# Error : pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Tags: graphviz, pydotplus

With Windows 10, Python 3.4 IDLE PyCharm
I tried to visualize the Tree of my model but it didn't work and I had the error below :

```
import graphviz
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image
import pydotplus

dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True,feature_names = list(X_train.columns) ,class_names=['0','1'])
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())

graph.write_png('tree.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

The Error is :

```
# Error : pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps :

- Install the App Graphviz (https://graphviz.org/download/)
- Install graphviz ( pip install graphviz )
- Install pydotplus ( pip install pydotplus )
  It does not work without having the App in the right env path.

Comment: I found that links for Windows are invalid. Any suggestions?